# How does the scipy distance_transform_edt function work?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, edt

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html

I'm having trouble understanding how the Euclidean distance transform function works in Scipy. From what I understand, it is different than the Matlab function (bwdist). As an example, for the input:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_edt function returns the same array:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

But the matlab function returns this:

```
1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361    3.1623
1.0000         0    1.0000    2.0000    2.2361
1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
2.2361    2.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000
3.1623    2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
```

which makes more sense, as it is returning the "distance" to the nearest one.

Comment: FYI, the scipy source code links to [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org.proxy.lib.fsu.edu/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1177156).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not clear from the docstring, but [`distance_transform_edt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt.html) computes the distance from non-zero (i.e. non-background) points to the nearest zero (i.e. background) point.

For example:

```
In [42]: x
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [43]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3)  # Easier to read the result with fewer digits.

In [44]: distance_transform_edt(x)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  2.   ,  3.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  1.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  2.   ,  2.236],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  1.414,  1.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.   ,  1.414],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```

You can get the equivalent of Matlab's `bwdist(a)` by applying `distance_transform_edt()` to `np.logical_not(a)` (i.e. invert the foreground and background):

```
In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [72]: distance_transform_edt(np.logical_not(a))
Out[72]: 
array([[ 1.414,  1.   ,  1.414,  2.236,  3.162],
       [ 1.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  2.   ,  2.236],
       [ 1.414,  1.   ,  1.414,  1.   ,  1.414],
       [ 2.236,  2.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ],
       [ 3.162,  2.236,  1.414,  1.   ,  1.414]])
```

Comment: how could I use the resulting matrix to calculate a ratio of distances?

Comment: @mLstudent33, that's not a question for the comments.  Create a new question, showing what you are trying to do, what you've tried so far, etc. (i.e. follow all the usual guidelines for a good question).

Answer (score 2):

Warren has already explained how `distance_transform_edt` works.
In your case,you could change sampling units along x and y

```
ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

But

```
>>> ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a, sampling=[2,2])
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Or

```
ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a, sampling=[3,3])
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```